# だとよ at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, word-choice, words

I watched a show in which person A tells person B they want them to come back. After it's said, person C said " datoyo." I don't understand it. Da to yo is used to quote things but why would you quote person A if person B heard him? Could it simply be that person C is agreeing with what person A said? Like saying " yeah, what he said. " to avoid repeating it?

Comment: Does A tell the other two what to do all the time and they don't particularly like it?

Comment: No. Person A  tried to reach out to person C

Comment: Is C (or B) reluctant to go back?

Comment: Yes. Person A says emotional words trying  to get person C to come back and then person B says datoyo. I only want to know if it could mean that B agrees with her words but instead of saying his own words just says datoyo

Comment: I thought C said that to B. Anyways, whichever of the two said it to the other, it simply means something like “You heard her. That’s what she wants.” The speaker may be trying to convince the listener to accept the situation and follow the order. It doesn’t necessarily mean he agrees with the person who gave the order. He may be equally reluctant to follow it.

Comment: Oh yes your'e right.  For more context, it's not an order. There are 2 people  trying to get someone they love to come back. What i wonder is if ir could it mean person C  agrees with the sentiment or can it only be specifically  about what person A wants?

Comment: naruto is right. There is nothing that indicates whether the speaker agrees or not. He seems to think the listener will listen to the first person better than to him.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C said だとよ to B, and assuming everyone is at the same place, yes, C is basically "quoting" A's statement. Its purpose is to confirm B heard what A said, and to prompt B's response. It's something like "So that's what A is saying, huh?", "(B,) you heard what A said?", "(B,) what do you say after A said this?", etc. Note that saying だとよ by itself does not necessary mean C has agreed with A.

Comment: But it could mean he agreed and wants to avoid saying what person A said himself? Person C is shy